# How to match similar strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have to arrays that contain names of premier league players.
I want to match them by name since the player objects don't have unique ids.

How can I make a string comparison that will match `Zlatan Ibrahimovic` with `Zlatan Ibrahimović` for example? (notice the last character of both strings)

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are your friend.

Comment: but therefore I would have to know each representation of one letter in the other name, right?

Comment: You would have to know that a "c" with an accent mark is "equivalent" to a "c" without one. But there's no way for the computer to know that without you telling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a trivial problem.
You should look into **Levenshtein distance** problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

You can search in google for different implementations or use a library like:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/levenshtein

Example:

```
l = new Levenshtein( 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic', 'Zlatan Ibrahimović')
// l === 1
```

I used already, and I liked. In my code, I used this one for an experimental proposed.

I don;t care about the result. Because in a long string 4 can be a very good number and in small one 2 it is very bad.

I get to do something like l/Math.max(str1.length, str2.length) then you can make your number and decide wich number is interesting for you.

Comment: The Levenshtein distance is used for calculating the minimal number of edits to make two strings equivalent, right? I don't think that's what OP is trying to accomplish. Just using the Levenshtein distance and a threshold of 2, `Zlatan` and `Klatap` would match.